# How to preprocess image so that tesseract can easily detect text in it

Tags: tesseract

I have this image, and I want to detect its text.

[image]

The image is relatively straightforward, but Tesseract still detects the text as LbOF.

I ran the command `tesseract foo.png -`
The output was
`Estimating resolution as 381 LbOF`

How should I preprocess the image so that it would be easy for Tesseract to decode this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
tesseract foo.png -
Estimating resolution as 381
Lb9F
```

It works out of the box with your image. What version are you using (tesseract and langdata)?

Comment: https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/using-tesseract-ubuntu/
I used the above link to follow the installation procedure for downloading. However, I installed the latest version of leptonica.